# How to eliminate duplication row in R when using merge function

Tags: r, merge

here is my code:

```
time=seq(as.Date('2020-4-1'),to=as.Date('2022-3-29'),by='1 weeks')
df=merge(FL_ratio,time)
```

I want to merge these two data sets. However, the result shows my many duplicate rows the total row number for FL_ratio is 104, and the row number for Time is 104 as well. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPCS4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whXWT.png)

i check the duplication as well. The result shows me there are 10,816 entries. It really confuse me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppigw.png)

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3yfb.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Both `time` and `FL_ratio` seem to be vectors, but `merge` is for data frames. Can you show a little bit of your expected result? A merge usually relies on exact matching, but your  vectors look very different. Mayne you're looking for `paste` or something? Without your expected result it is hard to tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data.frame(FL_ratio, time)`.

The `merge(...)` function is not meant for this. Since `time` and `FL_ratio` are vectors, `merge(FL_ratio, time)` will produce a cross-product: for each element of `FL_ratio` there will be rows for all the values of `time`. This is why you're getting 10,816 rows. You can see this below:

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 4:6
merge(x,y)
##   x y
## 1 1 4
## 2 2 4
## 3 3 4
## 4 1 5
## 5 2 5
## 6 3 5
## 7 1 6
## 8 2 6
## 9 3 6

data.frame(x,y)
##   x y
## 1 1 4
## 2 2 5
## 3 3 6
```